# Read elasticache from lambda - Cant connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, redis

I made an elasticache redis instance

```
Engine: Redis
Size: cache.t2.micro
Number of nodes: 1 node
Status available
```

I made an inbound rule on the security group this is using. It allows all traffic on all ports which allowed me to query my postgres RDS from a lambda so I dont think this is the problem.

I then try and connect via my lambda function

I set my env variables as...

```
REDIS_HOST=endpoint from elasticache
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

My lambda code

```
const { REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT } = process.env
const redis = require( 'redis' ).createClient({ host: REDIS_HOST, port: REDIS_PORT })

exports.handler = async event => {
 ...
```

With this i get the error `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

Since the endpoint elasticache gives me has a port on the end, i tried it as a url

```
const redis = require( 'redis' ).createClient({ url: REDIS_HOST })
```

Which gives me a timeout error

Im not sure if its the vpc/ lambda code or elasticache config

Comment: 1. Is lambda running within vpc? 2. Do you have Redis Auth enabled? 3. Do you have Encryption In-Transit enabled?

Comment: 1. this might be the problem, checking now, 2 im not sure. the 'redis AUTH default user access' is set to no. Is this what you mean? 3 no

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to prefix the URL with `rediss://REDIS_HOST`.

[Lambda Elasticache redis connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72512526/lambda-elasticache-redis-connection-refused/74135349#74135349)

That should help; Assuming you have the lambda and elasticache in the same VPC and the security group has an inbound rule set.

Comment: the double ss was my problem, thank you!